# Setting a default value for JOINS on multiple tables with possible empty resultsets?

Tags: mysql

So I'm trying to do a join on multiple with the same id and each table may or may not have an entry with that id.

```
SELECT a.value, b.value, c.value, d.value FROM tbl_a a 
JOIN tbl_b b ON a.id=b.id 
JOIN tbl_c c ON a.id=c.id
JOIN tbl_d d on a.id=d.id
WHERE a.id=123
```

Obviously this is failing because if tbl_a doesn't have doesn't have an entry, it returns an empty resultset and the joins fail.

I've tried all sorts of left joins, outer joins and couldn't get it to work. I've also tried setting the were clause to be like: `WHERE a.id=123 OR b.id=123 OR ...` but that didn't work either.

I tried an ugly UNION but that gives the output in a separate row.

```
SELECT count(*), "a", IFNULL(a.value,0) FROM tbl_a a WHERE a.id=123
UNION
SELECT count(*), "b", IFNULL(b.value,0) FROM tbl_b b WHERE b.id=123
UNION
etc...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the other three `id` fields to the `WHERE` clause with `OR`, then do outer joins.

Comment: I see, I was doing a left outer join, I should be doing a right outer join and it seems to work.

Comment: I tried the query, but the explain says it doesn't use the index on id: SELECT a.value, b.value, c.value, d.value FROM tbl_a a RIGHT OUTER JOIN tbl_b b ON b.id=a.id RIGHT OUTER JOIN tbl_c c ON c.id=a.id RIGHT OUTER JOIN tbl_d d ON d.id=a.id WHERE a.id=123 OR b.id=123 OR c.id=123 OR d.id=123

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to create a derived table containing your desired key and LEFT JOIN-ing to all the other tables:

```
SELECT a.value, b.value, c.value, d.value 
FROM ( select 123 as id ) as dummy
LEFT JOIN tbl_a a ON dummy.id=a.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_b b ON dummy.id=b.id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_c c ON dummy.id=c.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_d d ON dummy.id=d.id
```